# Trying to Find Compatible 15A Tandem Breaker for Older Electrical Panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I need to replace a 20A tandem breaker with a 15A tandem in order to protect 14 gauge wiring on two circuits in my home. The circuits are in the bedrooms and family room, respectively, (no kitchen, bathroom, or laundry receptacles) and everything on the circuits is rated for 15A or less. Unfortunately, the label/diagram for my panel is missing. It's a CTL panel with 20 slots.  I've uploaded photos that (hopefully) contain enough information to help determine what type of 15A tandem breaker I need. Can anyone help shed some light on this situation? I'm guessing I need a BR type without the physical restrictions, but I'm not sure if the brand matters. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

There's probably a big sheet of labeling somewhere, often hiding *on the inside* of the deadfront that you removed.

However, if you see Challenger, Westinghouse or BRyant, then what you want is an Eaton BD1515.  These panels (through a complex evolution) end up as the Eaton BR family, which if you look is cross-listed Type A or Type C.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I noticed that the BD is cheaper than the BR and more widely available. But the former has some physical restrictions built in (to prevent overloading a panel?). Am I okay going with the BD type because there's a notch in the bus bar on my panel? Just trying to understand the difference between the two.

Comment: @Justin yes, I'm looking right at the notch.  It's plainly there.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for your help

Comment: I can't access the cable jackets to determine if each hot wire has a neutral (in order to eliminate the possibility of a MWBC). As an alternative solution, can I replace both of the adjacent BD2020 tandems with BD1520 and still keep 240V between the (theoretical) MWBC hots?  That way I can protect the 14 gauge wires in the house without upsetting the (theorectical) MWBC balance.

Comment: @Justin ask that as a whole new question.